# fstrim "the discard operation is not supported" with ext4 on LVM

Tags: linux, lvm, fstrim

Attempting to run fstrim on my root partition (which is ext4 on a LVM logical volume, single physical volume—an SSD supporting TRIM) produces an error:

```
fstrim -v /
fstrim: /: the discard operation is not supported
```

However, running it on a different LV in the *same* single-PV volume group works just fine. Mount options for both (according to `/proc/mounts`) are the same: `rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered`.

`issue_discards = 1` is set in `lvm.conf`, if that matters.

Why would only one of them support trimming?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out there was a LVM snapshot of the root filesystem's LV, but not the other. Appears snapshots block TRIM, because the device-mapper snapshot target doesn't support it.